# Addition by date in EXCEL 2010

Tags: excel

Bonjour,
Hello,

I've got a col B with a date (14.01.2013, 16.02.2013...)
I've got a col L with a value ((149, 253...)

I want to auto add each value of J that are in the same month given by B.

In fact, I need 12 value, one for each month.

I try something like this :

`=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B300>=DATEVAL("01.01.2013"))*(B1:B300<=DATEVAL("31.01.2013"))*(L1:L300))`

but it's only work for the first value...

See this picture for more info :
[image]

Comment: U can use pivot table to do this. Much easier that way

Answer (score 1):

In O4 : =SUM ((MOIS(B:B)=N5)*(J:J)) with Matrix calculation

Comment: You could also use SUMPRODUCT to avoid "array entry", e.g. in English =SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(B$2:B$300)=N5)+0;L$2:L$300)